# Changing text on UILabel that is on top of camera preview layer makes it blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I have been using `AVFoundation` to get preview from camera. Here is how i set it up:

```
 // create session
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
_session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

// configure device
AVCaptureDevice *device;
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
for (AVCaptureDevice *singleDevice in devices) {
    if ([singleDevice hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
        if ([singleDevice position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            device = singleDevice;
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"Supported frame rates: %@",[device activeFormat].videoSupportedFrameRateRanges);
AVFrameRateRange* frameRange = [[device activeFormat].videoSupportedFrameRateRanges firstObject];

[device lockForConfiguration:nil];
[device setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:frameRange.minFrameDuration];
[device setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:frameRange.maxFrameDuration];
[device unlockForConfiguration];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (deviceInput) {
    [_session addInput:deviceInput];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Some wierd shit happened");
    return;
}

// set preview layer (camera output)
_previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
_previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
_previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.cameraView.frame.size.width, self.cameraView.frame.size.height);
_previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = [self videoOrientationFromCurrentDeviceOrientation];
[self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:_previewLayer];
```

And its ok working. Now above camera view i have overlay view that has `UILabel`. When i want to change text of that label in code, it changes but for a second, preview layer blinks, like its frozen for split second. I don't know why this is happening, does someone have more experience with this?